# ASP.NET Calling methods on user controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-user-controls

I have created an user control as follows to upload images. In it's code behind I have the method to save the image.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UCImageUploader.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="WebApplicationFor_ABC.UCImageUploader" %>
<div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadImage" runat="server" />
    <asp:Image ID="ImageThumbnail" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="LblMsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete"/>

</div>
```

code behind as follows

```
 public partial class UCImageUploader : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public bool SaveImg()
        {
                        //file field isn't empty
        if (FileUploadImage.PostedFile != null)
        {

            //check file size
            HttpPostedFile img = FileUploadImage.PostedFile;

            if (img.ContentLength == 0) // no file uploaded
            {
                msg = "No file was uploaded";
                LblMsg.Text = msg;
                return false;
            }
            else if (img.ContentLength > fileSizeInKB * 1024) // file size exceeds limit
            {
                msg = "File size exceeds the limit. Max is " + fileSizeInKB + "KB";
                LblMsg.Text = msg;
                return false;
            }
            else // accepted file size
            {
                //check file extension jpg,jpeg,BMP

                string[] fileExtensions = { "jpg", "jpeg", "bmp" };

                if (!fileExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(img.FileName).ToLower()))
                {
                    msg = "File extension must be of jpg,jpeg,bmp";
                    LblMsg.Text = msg;
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }
        msg = "Valid File";
        LblMsg.Text = msg;
        return valid;
    }
```

On another button's click event I want to call this `SaveImg()` method and save the Image. The problem is because of the postback image returns as null. How can i fix this.

Comment: The problem should be in the `SaveImg` method (or who knows). Without sharing it I believe no one will be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the image, you do not do this through the file upload control, e.g.

```
FileUploadImage.SaveAs(savePath);
```

Comment: Then how can I call the method defined in the control? Is there anyway I can call this method and access the data passed without losing them between the postbacks..